# How to find best features using statistical tests?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

I am new to Machine Learning and the first part where I am stuck is identifying which features are best for the model. I understand that usually correlation heat map shows the input and output correlation matrix and we can deduce some better predictors for our model. But in my case, I have around 200 or so numerical features and my output target T is binary - 0 or 1. So, in this classification problem, I want to know what kind of statistical tests can be used to understand which predictors are good, before even going into modeling process.

I have read a bit about chi-sq and t-tests but I dont know which one is applied when and how is the output interpreted.

Any help or links with regards to this problem is much appreciated.